# Не отображаются изображения в JSP

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, сервлеты

Здравствуйте,объясните как отобразить image1.jpg?
Структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Читал похожие темы,где то написано что изображения и прочий контент должны быть расположены в папке webapp,кто то пишет что можно расположить отдельно от папки webapp(упоминается jstl).
p.s.До сих пор непонятно почему вообще картинки не отображаются,если в сервлете указано urlPatterns = {"/"} ниже давали ссылку,понял только что это плохая практика..

Comment: Всё дело в `urlPatterns = {"/"}`. Вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern один авторитетный чувак пишет, что это плохой шаблон для сервлета. Из-за этого перекрывается стандартный обработчик, который среди прочего отвечает и за картинки.

Comment: Можете сами перевести ответ из ссылки. Я столько не напишу и тем более не переведу. А чувака этого стоит перевести любителям java и web.